# Selenium Webdriver - (Java) - Click a button with dynamic ID

Tags: dynamic, selenium, webdriver, element

1) I have a `dialog` on my web page having 2 buttons, `Yes` & `No`.
2) `IDs` of these buttons are dynamicaly changing every time.
3) How to handle this situation and click on `Yes` button?
4) Both buttons, `Yes` & `No`, have same `classname` 1.e. `rwInnerSpan`
5) Here is the `Xpath` for `Yes` button
`(.//*[@id='confirm1381468352443_content']/div/div[2]/a[1]/span/span)`
the part `1381468352443` in xpath is `dynamically changing`.

Below is the source code of page
`

```
<tr class="rwTitleRow">  
<tr class="rwContentRow">  
<td class="rwCorner rwBodyLeft"> </td>  
<td class="rwWindowContent" valign="top">  
<iframe frameborder="0" name="confirm1381468352443" src="javascript:'<html></html>';" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0px none; display: none;" tabindex="0">
<div id="confirm1381468352443_content">  
<div class="rwDialogPopup">  
<div class="rwDialogText">  
<div>  
<a class="rwPopupButton" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$find('confirm1381468352443').close(true);" tabindex="-1">  
<span class="rwOuterSpan">  
<span class="rwInnerSpan">Yes</span>  
</span>    
</a>  
<a class="rwPopupButton" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$find('confirm1381468352443').close(false);" tabindex="-1">  
<span class="rwOuterSpan">  
<span class="rwInnerSpan">No</span>  
</span>  
</a>`
```

Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 1):

You can directly check for the text in your Xpath:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='rwPopupButton']/span/span[contains(text(), 'Yes')]"))
```

Comment: Hi Lefloh, thanks for your reply.
I tried your code but it did't recognized the "Yes" button. I believe there is some problem with "frame" & "popup" window. can you please review my another question based on same senario?.
here is the link to other question:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/19354893/1533847
Many Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to locate objects using partial link text, so you can try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Yes")).click();
```

Plain By.linkText may not work because of additional spaces or characters in the link.

Answer (score -1):

You can click on the button based on the Text. Following method will give you a webelement based on the class locator and text.

```
WebElement getElementBasedOnClassAndText(String classLocator, String text){
    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className(classLocator))
    for(WebElement element : elements){
        if(element.getText().contentEquals(text)){
            return element
        }
    }
    Assert.fail("Unable to find any element with the said Text")
}
```

Once you get the element you can take any action on it.

Comment: Hi Varun, thanks for your reply.
Please review my above comment in reply to Lefloh's answer and see if you can help.
Many Thanks !!

Answer (score -1):

Since it is dynamic I would look for the changed name:

```
//Find the dynamicly created ID
String dynamicID = driver.findElement(By
    .xpath("//iframe[contains(@name,'confirm')]")
        .getAttribute("name");
//Use that ID to find the Yes option
driver.findElement(By
    .xpath("//*[@id='"+dynamicID +"_content']/div/div[2]/a[1]/span/span")
            .click();
```