# Selenium Webdriver - (Java) - working with HTML dialogs

Tags: java, dialog, popup, selenium-webdriver

Here is the situation:

1. Click on `Import file` button (this action will upload a file).
2. After file upload, then appears a popup (HTML popup). I used `driver.switchTo().frame(1);` to switch to that popup and click "Next" in that popup.
3. Clicking `Next` will navigate user to second step in that popup. Click `process commission` button in that second step of popup.
4. After clicking `process commission` button, then appears a new confirmation popup (HTML popup).
5. I am not able to click `yes` in that confirmation popup.

I tried using:
`driver.switchTo().frame(0);` - did not work
`driver.switchTo().frame(1);` - did not work
`driver.switchTo().frame(2);` - did not work

Please suggest any solution.

```
<form id="Form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="ProcessCommission.aspx?i=2115&pn=Manage+Commission&j=2345&prn=Process+Commission" method="post">
<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="javascript:'<html></html>';" style="position: fixed; width: 400px; height: 100px; left: 431px; top: 53px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); z-index: 3003;" tabindex="-1">  
<div id="RadWindowWrapper_confirm1381733327500" class="RadWindow RadWindow_Windows7 rwNormalWindow rwTransparentWindow" style="width: 400px; height: 100px; position: absolute; transform: none; backface-visibility: visible; visibility: visible; left: 431px; top: 377px; z-index: 3003;" unselectable="on">  
<table class="rwTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="height: 51px;">  
<tbody>  
<tr class="rwTitleRow">  
<tr class="rwContentRow">  
<td class="rwCorner rwBodyLeft"> </td>
<td class="rwWindowContent" valign="top">  
<iframe frameborder="0" name="confirm1381733327500" src="javascript:'<html></html>';" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0px none; display: none;" tabindex="0">  
<div id="confirm1381733327500_content">  
<div class="rwDialogPopup">  
<div class="rwDialogText">  
<div>
<a class="rwPopupButton" href="javascript:void(0); "onclick="$find('confirm1381733327500').close(true);" tabindex="-1">
<span class="rwOuterSpan">  
<span class="rwInnerSpan">Yes</span>  
</span>
</a>  
<a class="rwPopupButton" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$find('confirm1381733327500').close(false);" tabindex="-1">  
<span class="rwOuterSpan">  
<span class="rwInnerSpan">No</span>  
</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
driver.switchto.frame(0)
driver.switchto.frame(confirm1381733327500)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

```
dr.SwitchTo().Frame(dr.FindElement(By.TagName("iframe")));
dr.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
dr.FindElement(By.XPath("your stuff goes here").Click();
dr.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();//switch back to default content of original page
```

Comment: Care to add an explanation?